# Calling .filter on row chart with reduce functions give zero results

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a row chart which has a reduce function in its group, everytime I call .filter([something]) it will give zero results, it works fine for other charts.

Here's the code for the rowchart

```
reduceAdd(p, v) {
    v.conditions.forEach (function(val, idx) {
        p[val] = (p[val] || 0) + 1; //increment counts
    });
    return p;
    }

reduceRemove(p, v) {
    v.conditions.forEach (function(val, idx) {
        p[val] = (p[val] || 0) - 1; //decrement counts
    });
    return p;
    }

reduceInitial() {
    return {};  
    }

var conditionDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ 
    return d.conditions;
});
var conditionGroup = conditionDim.groupAll().reduce(this.reduceAdd, this.reduceRemove, this.reduceInitial).value();
conditionGroup.all = function() {
    var newObject = [];
    for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && key != "all") {
        newObject.push({
            key: key,
            value: this[key],
        });
        }
    }
    return newObject;
    }

dc.rowChart(`.chart .conditions`)                                                                           
    .width(300)
    .height(500)
    .group(conditionGroup)
    .elasticX(true)
    .dimension(conditionDim)
    .filterHandler((dimension, filters) => {
                        dimension.filter(null);   
                        if (filters.length === 0)
                            dimension.filter(null);
                        else
                            dimension.filterFunction(function (d) {
                                if (difference(filters, d).length === 0) return true;
                                return false; 
                            });
                        return filters;  
                    })
```

I find that when I call chart.filter([something]) the value on reduce function is already undefined.

I still can filter the row chart by clicking the chart itself, but not by calling .filter(). I thought they work the same way, if anyone can tell me the difference that'd be great.

OR

Anyone know what else might be the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: They should work the same. You could use a breakpoint in `.filter()` to see what is happening differently in the two cases (since the UI calls the function). This isn't enough of an example for me to tell what is going wrong, but that is sure one heck of a complicated reduction. The keys that are produced by your group should match the keys of the dimension, otherwise filtering definitely won't work.

Comment: It looks like you may be using an old and timeworn hack for doing a tag dimension, where each row contributes to multiple keys (has an array of keys). [This is directly supported by the community fork of crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays), which may help.

Comment: You won't need a `filterHandler` if you use the feature above; if you stick with your current code, it looks like `difference(filters, d).length === 0` would test for exact equality when you really want to test for intersection of two arrays.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for your answer, yes, that was a hack for doing dimension with array values. The reason I didn't do it directly was because I'm still using older version of crosfilter on my project. I tried updating it but it broke the project.

Comment: I see. I think you want `intersection(filters, d).length > 0` but again it's not enough code to really tell what's going on. I think you'll also run into problems if you try to select more than one bar... you'll have to make sure to filter by an array of values since your filterFunction expects that... even then I'm not sure if it will work since there are some weird special cases in `.filter()` having to do with arrays. I'd really need a running example to help you further.

Comment: @Gordon I tried to make a working example with stackblitz, its my first time using it, I'm not sure what's the error from. Do you mind to have a look? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpdn7w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Also I have tried updating Crossfilter to 1.4.6 so that I don't need the reduce function, but I still got the same error. The filter works when I click from UI but not from calling .filter()

Comment: Wait, you got an error? You should always add the error text to your question (no matter how cryptic ;). Or do you just mean it fails in the same way? I'll take a look at the stackblitz now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how to troubleshoot your stackblitz. It is transpiled to hell and back and I can't find the actual code in there.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your help. I gave up on the stackblitz as well. But I have tried using the newer version of crossfilter so I can use `.ndx.dimension(function(d){ 
                return d.conditions;
            }, true);` Apparently, its still the same, when I click on the chart it filter fine, but when I call .filter it always give 0 results.

Comment: with the new crossfilter you shouldn't need the `filterHandler`. other than that i have no idea. they should work the same. you should put a breakpoint in `.filter()` and make sure you really are passing the same format that the chart passes internally.

Comment: also you need `chart.redrawGroup()` after `.filter`. i can't find any example of how you are calling `.filter` in the code above or in the stackblitz but maybe i don't know where to look.

Comment: @Gordon I finally managed to make it work, but I'm pretty sure that there's bug on .filter on filtering multi value. So what i do is to call .filter on a loop when I have multiple filter value. For example if I need .filter(["A","B"]), i'll do  .filter("A") then .filter("B"). I don't know if this is a bad practice, but it works.

Comment: @Gordon I still need to retain the filterHandler, because the default filter on row chart is using OR instead of AND.I mean is that the default filter will show more data the more you add the filter, and I want the other way around.

Comment: You never said you were trying to filter multiple values! This is why putting the relevant code in the question is so important. You want `.filter([["A", "B"]])` (notice extra brackets, yes it's weird); it's [documented here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filter__anchor). So your actual question had nothing to do with reduction or filter handlers at all.

Comment: I'm so sorry I missed that, I didn't know before that its only not working for multiple values which is why I didn't mention it. I tried adding bracket on .filter() , and it works beautifully. Thanks heap.

Comment: That's great! Often the work is finding the right question, and that's how we end up with these long comment threads that mods hate. ;-) Glad it's finally working for you.